# Passing values from One Asp.net solution to another asp.net solution in same server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actually, I have "Test Solution" having login page, and redirects to home page in same solution. In this home page i have link button to navigate "Result Solution". For this scenario, generally we are using href.

but, Now I need the credentials of Test Solution into Result Solution. How can I get those..?

I Tried,

If we are using Sessions, we not able to access in different solutions.
If we are using QueryString, The credentials will be displayed in URL.

Note: These 2 solutions are separate from each other but placed in same server.

Comment: You are heading towards wrong direction. look into `OAuth` or `OpenIdConnect` and pass an `Access Token` rather

Comment: And you might want to explore the term "Single Sign-On".